# How to load a bunch of session variables to another controller function with codeigniter and insert them in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im trying to write a code where a form will store all of its values inside session variables when the submit button is pressed and go to the next page where there is another form waiting to be filled up. when the submit button for the form in page 2 is pressed the variables will be stored in a session then the contents of the session variables/array will be inserted in the database. and i seem to be having problems

Summary:

1. Page 1 - User fills up form and the variables will be stored in a session array upon submit
2. Page 2 - user fills up another form and the variables will be stored in a session array upon submit
3. the session variables in page 1 and 2 will be inserted in the database

here is my code:

controller(site.php)

```
        public function m1()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['m1']))
            {
                $suffix = $this->input->post("suffix");
                $fn = $this->input->post("fn");
                $mn = $this->input->post("mn");
                $ln = $this->input->post("ln");
                $nickname = $this->input->post("nickname");
                $sex = $this->input->post("sex");
                $bday = $this->input->post("bday");
                $street = $this->input->post("street");
                $city = $this->input->post("city");
                $province = $this->input->post("province");
                $region = $this->input->post("region");
                $landline = $this->input->post("landline");
                $cellphone = $this->input->post("cellphone");
                $email = $this->input->post("email");
                $edu_level = $this->input->post("edu_level");
                $course = $this->input->post("course");
                $school_name = $this->input->post("school_name");
                $school_address = $this->input->post("school_address");
                $school_province = $this->input->post("school_province");
                $school_city = $this->input->post("school_city");
                $school_region = $this->input->post("school_region");

                $newdata = array('suffix'=>$suffix,
                                'fn'=>$fn,
                                'mn'=>$mn,
                                'ln'=>$ln,
                                'nickname'=>$nickname,
                                'sex'=>$sex,
                                'bday'=>$bday,
                                'street'=>$street,
                                'city'=>$city,
                                'province'=>$province,
                                'region'=>$region,
                                'landline'=>$landline,
                                'cellphone'=>$cellphone,
                                'email'=>$email,
                                'edu_level'=>$edu_level,
                                'course'=>$course,
                                'school_name'=>$school_name,
                                'school_address'=>$school_address,
                                'school_province'=>$school_province,
                                'school_city'=>$school_city,
                                'school_region'=>$school_region,
                                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

                redirect(base_url() . "site/cmain/m/2");    
            }

        }

        public function m2()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['m2']))
            {
                $nature_complaint = $this->input->post("nature_complaint");
                $newdata = array('nature_complaint'=>$nature_complaint);
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                $this->db->insert('myself', $newdata); 
                redirect(base_url() . "site/cmain/m/3");    
            }
        }
```

the problem with my code is that the session variables for page 2(public function m2()) is the only one that gets inserted in the database.
is there a way to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In the first function (M1)

set your newdata in this way

```
$this->session->set_userdata('newdata', $newdata);
```

### In second function (M2)

```
    public function m2()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['m2']))
        {
            $nature_complaint = $this->input->post("nature_complaint");

            $newdata = array();
            $newdata = $this->session->userdata('newdata');
            $newdata['nature_complaint'] = $nature_complaint;

            $this->session->set_userdata('newdata', $newdata);

            $this->db->insert('myself', $newdata); 
            redirect(base_url() . "site/cmain/m/3");    
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have another question,
when i use this code i can no longer echo out the session variables.
this is how i echo them out

<?php echo $this->session->userdata('fn'); ?>

is there another way to echo out a session variable?

Comment: you show exit it before redirecting.

print_r($newdata);
exit;

Comment: it just says Undefined variable: newdata.

Comment: the session variables are being inserted in the database but i just cant echo them out

Answer (score 0):

Your $newData variable is getting reset in your second function. you have already stored $newData array to session. after resetting values in second function session contains only data from second function. you need to add data in $newData instead resetting it.

Comment: what does this mean "you need to add data in $newData instead resetting it." should i store the post in my second function to a new variable?